# QDial ange per revolution

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdial

I'm trying to make an Application with PyQt5, Python 3.7.3 using a Raspberry pi4B and a 5 inch touch screen.
The thing is that I need to make a QDial, but I want it to make more than one revolution if it goes from min range to max range. For example, if the Qdial has range from 0 to 500, I want it to make 100 points per revolution, so you have to do a full rotation 5 times to go from the min value to the max value.

This is what I've tried:
`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.dial = QDial()
        self.dial.setMinimum(0)
        self.dial.setMaximum(100)
        self.dial.setValue(40)
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderMoved)
        self.dial.setWrapping(True)
        self.text=QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.dial)
        layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.isHigher=False

    def sliderMoved(self):
        print("Dial value = %i" % (self.dial.value()))
        self.text.setText(str(self.dial.value()))
        if(self.dial.value()==100 and self.isHigher==False):
            self.higher_range()
            self.isHigher=True
        if(self.dial.value()==100 and self.isHigher==True):
            self.lower_range()
            self.isHigher=False



    def higher_range(self):
        self.dial.setRange(100,200)
        self.dial.setValue(105)

    def lower_range(self):
        self.dial.setRange(0,100)
        self.dial.setValue(95)



        

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`

But this doesn't work, It keeps changing from 95 to 105 and viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QDial is a pretty peculiar control. While it's still supported, it's poorly implemented, and I believe it's by choice: due to its nature, it's really hard to add more features. I had quite an amount of experience with it, and I know it's not an easy element to deal with.

One of its issues is that it represents a monodimensional range but, visually and UI speaking, it is a bidimensional object.

What you're trying to achieve *is* possible, but consider that an UI element should *always* display its state in a clear way and have a corresponding proper behavior; that's the only way UI can tell the user the state. Physical dials don't have this issue: you also have a *tactile* response that tells you when the gear reaches its end.

From my experience I could tell you that you should avoid it as much as possible: it seems a nice and intuitive widget, but in reality it's very difficult to get a proper result that is actually intuitive to the user. There are some instances for which it makes sense to use it (in my case, representation of a physical knob of an electronic musical instrument). I suggest you to do some research on [skeumorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph) and UX aspects.

That said, this is a possible **raw** implementation. I've overridden some aspects (most importantly, the `valueChanged` signal, for naming consistency), but for a proper implementation you should do much more work (and testing).

The trick is to set the range based on the number of "revolutions": if the maximum is 500 and 5 revolutions are chosen, then the dial will have an *actual* maximum of 100. Then, whenever the value changes, we check whether *previous* value was below or above the minimum/maximum of the actual range, and change the revolution count accordingly.

Two important notes:

- since QDial inherits from QAbstractSlider, it has a range(minimum, maximum + 1), and since the division could have some rest, the "last" revolution will have a different range;
- I didn't implement the wheel event, as that requires further inspection and choosing the appropriate behavior depending on the "previous" value and revolution;

```
class SpecialDial(QDial):
    _cycleValueChange = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, minimum=0, maximum=100, cycleCount=2):
        super().__init__()
        assert cycleCount > 1, 'cycles must be 2 or more'
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.cycle = 0
        self.cycleCount = cycleCount
        self._minimum = minimum
        self._maximum = maximum
        self._normalMaximum = (maximum - minimum) // cycleCount
        self._lastMaximum = self._normalMaximum + (maximum - minimum) % self._normalMaximum
        self._previousValue = super().value()
        self._valueChanged = self.valueChanged
        self.valueChanged = self._cycleValueChange
        self._valueChanged.connect(self.adjustValueChanged)

        self.setRange(0, self._normalMaximum)

    def value(self):
        return super().value() + self._normalMaximum * self.cycle

    def minimum(self):
        return self._minimum

    def maximum(self):
        return self._maximum()

    def dialMinimum(self):
        return super().minimum()

    def dialMaximum(self):
        return super().maximum()

    def adjustValueChanged(self, value):
        if value < self._previousValue:
            if (value < self.dialMaximum() * .3 and self._previousValue > self.dialMaximum() * .6 and 
                self.cycle + 1 < self.cycleCount):
                    self.cycle += 1
                    if self.cycle == self.cycleCount - 1:
                        self.setMaximum(self._lastMaximum)
        elif (value > self.dialMaximum() * .6 and self._previousValue < self.dialMaximum() * .3 and
            self.cycle > 0):
                self.cycle -= 1
                if self.cycle == 0:
                    self.setMaximum(self._normalMaximum)
        new = self.value()
        if self._previousValue != new:
            self._previousValue = value
            self.valueChanged.emit(self.value())

    def setValue(self, value):
        value = max(self._minimum, min(self._maximum, value))
        if value == self.value():
            return
        block = self.blockSignals(True)
        self.cycle, value = divmod(value, self._normalMaximum)
        if self.dialMaximum() == self._normalMaximum and self.cycle == self.cycleCount - 1:
            self.setMaximum(self._lastMaximum)
        elif self.dialMaximum() == self._lastMaximum and self.cycle < self.cycleCount - 1:
            self.setMaximum(self._normalMaximum)
        super().setValue(value)
        self.blockSignals(block)
        self._previousValue = self.value()
        self.valueChanged.emit(self._previousValue)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key in (Qt.Key_Right, Qt.Key_Up):
            step = self.singleStep()
        elif key in (Qt.Key_Left, Qt.Key_Down):
            step = -self.singleStep()
        elif key == Qt.Key_PageUp:
            step = self.pageStep()
        elif key == Qt.Key_PageDown:
            step = -self.pageStep()
        elif key in (Qt.Key_Home, Qt.Key_End):
            if key == Qt.Key_Home or self.invertedControls():
                if super().value() > 0:
                    self.cycle = 0
                    block = self.blockSignals(True)
                    super().setValue(0)
                    self.blockSignals(block)
                    self.valueChanged.emit(self.value())
            else:
                if self.cycle != self.cycleCount - 1:
                    self.setMaximum(self._lastMaximum)
                    self.cycle = self.cycleCount - 1
                if super().value() != self._lastMaximum:
                    block = self.blockSignals(True)
                    super().setValue(self._lastMaximum)
                    self.blockSignals(block)
                    self.valueChanged.emit(self.value())
            return
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
            return
        if self.invertedControls():
            step *= -1

        current = self.value()
        new = max(self._minimum, min(self._maximum, current + step))
        if current != new:
            super().setValue(super().value() + (new - current))


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.dial = SpecialDial()
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderMoved)
        self.text=QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.dial)
        layout.addWidget(self.text)

    def sliderMoved(self):
        self.text.setText(str(self.dial.value()))
```

I strongly suggest you to take your time to:

- consider is this is really what you want, since, as said, this kind of control can be very tricky from the UX perspective;
- carefully read the code and understand its logics;

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this actually helped me a lot. I think I will be able to implement this on the future, but as you said, I ended up using another widget instead of the Qdial.

Comment: Amazing answer musicamante. Kudos

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same and I found a solution. It is based on calculating the change of the dial number. If the dial number goes from the maximum to the minimum then it is considered as only increasing one unit.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QDial
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class DialWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label_number = 0
        self.label = QLabel(str(self.label_number), self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.dial = QDial(self)
        self.dial.setNotchesVisible(True)
        self.dial.setWrapping(True)
        self.dial.setMinimum(0)
        self.dial.setMaximum(100)  # 3600 for full revolutions (0-3600 = 0-360 degrees)

        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.dial_value_changed)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.dial)

        self.dial_value = self.dial.value()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.total_revolutions = 0

    def get_label_number(self):
        return self.label_number
    
    def set_label_number(self, number):
        self.label_number = number
        self.label.setText(str(self.label_number))

    def dial_value_changed(self):

        dial_delta = self.dial.value() - self.dial_value
        if dial_delta == 1:
            new_number = self.get_label_number() + 1
            self.set_label_number(new_number)
        elif dial_delta == -1:
            new_number =  self.get_label_number() - 1
            self.set_label_number(new_number)
        elif dial_delta == -100:
            new_number =  self.get_label_number() + 1
            self.set_label_number(new_number)
        elif dial_delta == 99:
            new_number =  self.get_label_number() - 1
            self.set_label_number(new_number)

        self.dial_value = self.dial.value()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DialWidget()
    window.setWindowTitle('Dial Widget')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This dial will need 5 full turns to increase the value from 0 to 500. It has problems with the speed at which you turn, though, and there is no maximum value, but I'm sure you could add it somehow.